# Is it possible to echo a variable which is declared below the echo in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, echo

The below code will not display any output as the variable is declared below the echo as PHP gets executed line by line. Is there any way to search for the variable in the whole page and then execute the code?

```
<?php
include "header.php";
$title = "Test";
?>
```

`header.php`

```
<html>
<head>
<title><? echo $title ?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: Why you want to display first and declare later? This doesn't go with programming concept. BTW what is your logic?

Comment: I have created an header file which I am going to several pages but the title varies in each page so I have coded the title as a variable `<title><?php echo "$title"; > - Domain.com</title>`

Comment: Why don't you create constants and use it wherever you want?

Comment: Turn your code upside down and it will work.Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to learn how [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)/[interpreters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) works. PHP is interpreted language and The binary that lets you interpret PHP is compiled.

PHP run from top to bottom.

so its like

```
<?php // start from here 

   echo "$title";   <-- $title is undefined here
   $title = "Test"; <-- now you declared $title with value so it goes in  memory now

     //end
```

So you need to  first check weather `$title` is set or not than respond according to it

```
if(isset($title)){
  echo $title;
}
```

Comment: Can I add some code to find the undefined variable `$title` in the page and then if it is found it will execute or return false?

Comment: yes you can check weather $title is set or not by `if(isset($title)){echo $title;}`

Answer (score -1):

According to your logic, I suggest you to use contants like below:
Create a separate file, let's say constant.php and include it on all other pages

```
<?
    define("TITLE", "This is title");

?>
```

Use it like below:

```
<?php echo TITLE;?>
```

Thanks